# Dynamic selectbox how to add options dynamically to a select box from my text boxes values

Tags: jquery, html

I am new for this type of functionality, how can i retrieve the textbox values and that every value appending to the beside select box option after clicking on add button Any One please give me a suggestion to fixed it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var val = $('#txt-val').val();
var selectval = $('#newval').val();
  $('#addbtn').click(function(){
  //who to retrive textbox value and append as a option value of select box .
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width:150px;" id="txt-val" />
<button id="addbtn">Add</button>
<select id="newval" style="width:150px;">
<option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a line of code you need to add

Use `.append()` in your `.click()` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#addbtn').click(function(){
    var val = $.trim($('#txt-val').val());
    if(val != '')
      $('#newval').append('<option>' + val +'</option>');
    $('#txt-val').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width:150px;" id="txt-val" />
<button id="addbtn">Add</button>
<select id="newval" style="width:150px;">
</select>
```

Comment: k nice but same value apending here repeatedly.

Comment: empty value should not append to select box how?

Comment: Ya Exactly Thanks

Comment: for the first option ( empty option ) not to appear , delete <option> from HTML

Comment: here its allowing spaces how to i override it as empty

Comment: @SamudralaRamu Check the answer now. Using $.trim(); would fix that.